# datagridview .get cell value without leaving row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which the user enters a value . As he enters , new row gets added and user is able to enter his new value.

[image]

As the user enters names , more rows keep getting added. When the user is done entering all names , he clicks a button and I need to do something using every name entered in the grid view.

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
                {

                    string user = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                   // do something using the string user
               }
           }
```

This is the code I am using to read each row. The problem I am facing is that v

`row.Cells[0].Value` doesn't seem to catch the last active row.

eg. if the user has just typed "Tim" , he is forced to go to the next empty row to ensure Tim also gets read by the above code.  If he still keeps cursor in the Tim cell after typing , the above code doesn't capture "Tim" .

How can I solve this problem ? I would prefer to do this without using any `CellChange` event or any event. I have full row select as `Selection Mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620.aspx), you need to call `dataGridView1.EndEdit()`. Note that this method will throw an exception if this edit can't be closed (i.e., the data in the cell does not satisfy all input validation criteria).

Comment: That seemed to work . I did an EndEdit, before my above for loop. However let me wait to see if there is another way. +1 for you.